# Transferring 2003 terminal server licenses from one server to another

Tags: windows-server-2003, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Does anyone know how to transfer terminal server licenses from one windows 2003 server standard edition to another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Sahus Pilwal

Answer (score 1):

This article describes [How to transfer Terminal Services licenses from one computer to another](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248430), and it's on microsoft's site.

It came up as the first result when I googled for "How to transfer terminal services licenses"